# How to delete a specific row in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I delete a specific row in Julia? Let's say I have an array:

```
[A , 2
 B , 4
 C , 6]
```

I want to delete the lines for which 'B' is in the first column. I can identify which row this is, but am not able to delete this row. Can anybody help me?

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 12):

```
julia> a = rand(1:10, 5,3)
5×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  4  5   7
  8  4   3
  8  6   3
 10  4   1
  9  3  10
```

To delete row 4:

```
julia> row = 4
julia> a = a[setdiff(1:end, row), :]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5   7
 8  4   3
 8  6   3
 9  3  10
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a dataframe called "data".

```
julia> data=DataFrame(rand(1:10, 5,3))
5×3 DataFrames.DataFrame 
Row  x1  x2  x3 
1    9   1   1   
2    8   5   8
3    9   2   2  
4    9   6   5  
5    3   8   7
```

You want to delete entire row where column x1 has value 8.

```
julia> data[data[:x1].!=8,:]
4×3 DataFrames.DataFrame

Row  x1  x2  x3 
1    9   1   1   
2    9   2   2  
3    9   6   5  
4    3   8   7
```

Comment: This isn't deleting the row, it's returning a view on the DataFrame.